# VC++ DLL compilation using NMAKE

Tags: c++, dll, linker, nmake, cl

I have a DLL file compiled using Visual Studio 2005 and it works perfectly, when I call those functions(in DLL) from a C# program. But if I compile the same program using NMAKE , it compiles successfully but it doesn't work with the C# program. I get a "**DLL NOT FOUND EXCEPTION**" or "**DLL IS CORRUPT**".

P.S: I copied all the compiler options and Linker options from the Original project file and used it in the **MakeFile** but still of no use. What am I missing out here?

Compiler and Linker options as follows:

```
Compiler opt: /O2 /Ob1 /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WRITE_LOGS" /D "_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0700" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_MBCS" /Fo"obj\\" /FD /EHsc /MD /W3 /nologo /c /Gz /TP /errorReport:prompt 

Linker opt: /OUT:"dll/XXX.dll" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /DLL /DEF:"src\XXX.def" /DELAY:UNLOAD /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT mqrt.lib ..(other lib files)..
```

**Edit:** If I use **dumpbin**, the size of "HEADERS","EXPORTS","SYMBOLS" are all less in the DLL compiled using NMAKE than the DLL compiled using Visual studio !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my fault. I just didn't include a part of the actual compilation. The important part I guess.

**Embedding the manifest file to the DLL**

The **Mt.exe** file is a tool that generates signed files and catalogs. I found [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235591.aspx) and it was so useful.

**P.S:** I learnt this. The three important parts of compiling a DLL are,

- COMPILER(CL.exe)
- LINKER(LINK.exe)
- Embedding manifest (MT.exe)

Comment: Using mt.exe actually manifests the .def file with the DLL, thereby helping other applications to find the functions within the DLL.